# C++ matrix - Get number of columns where the lowest value is in the same row as the highest value in the columns after it

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm writing a program in C++ where the inputs are N (the number of villages/rows), M (the number of days/columns) and an H[N][M]
matrix where I individually input the temperatures (min -50, max 50).

The output should be the total number of days when the village with the lowest
temperature has the highest forecast temperature, and after that the number (column) of these days in ascending order.

So if I input something like this:

```
3 5 
10 15 12 10 10
11 11 11 11 20
12 16 16 16 20
```

The output should be:

```
2 2 3
```

Or input:

```
3 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
2 1 2
```

My approach was to first store the minimum temperatures and maximum forecast temperatures of each day into two separate arrays and
then writing a for loop where I check each village day by day if they contain both the minimum value on the given day and maximum forecast temperatures from that day on.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int maxarr = 1000;
int H[maxarr][maxarr];

using namespace std;

void read(int N, int M, int t[maxarr][maxarr]);
void count(int N, int M, int t[maxarr][maxarr]);

int main()
{
    int N;
    int M;
    cout<<"Number of villages? ";
    cin>>N;
    cout<<"Number of days? ";
    cin>>M;
    read(N,M,H);
    count(N,M,H);

    return 0;
}

void read(int N, int M, int t[maxarr][maxarr])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M ; j++)
        {
            cin>>t[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void count(int N, int M, int t[maxarr][maxarr])
{
    int mintemparr[maxarr];
    int maxtemparr[maxarr];
    int mintemp;
    int maxtemp;
    int days[maxarr];
    int cnt = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j<M; j++)
    {
        mintemp = 51;
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        {
            if(t[i][j]<mintemp)
            {
                mintemp = t[i][j];
            }
            mintemparr[j] = mintemp;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < M-1; i++)
    {
        maxtemp = -51;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            for(int k = i+1; k < M; k++)
            {
                if(t[j][k]>maxtemp)
                {
                    maxtemp = t[j][k];
                }
            }
            maxtemparr[i] = maxtemp;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < M-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            for(int k = i+1; k < M; k++)
            {
                if(t[j][i] == mintemparr[i])
                {
                    if(t[j][k] == maxtemparr[i])
                    {
                        days[cnt] = i+1;
                        cnt++;
                        //tried an i++ here, didn't work as intended
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<cnt<<" ";
    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        cout<<days[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

There are some instances where it works perfectly, for example with the first input it's output is as it should be. But with the
second input I get

```
6 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

and a longer (1000x1000) input, which I obviously can't copy here also gives wrong results.
How could I make this code work as intended?

Comment: You state that "The output should be the total number of days when the village with the lowest temperature has the highest forecast temperature". I assume the values you provided in the input are the forecast temperatures. But where do you get the actual temperatures from? Can you please explain how you got to the output `2 2 3` based on the input provided?

Comment: All right, so the first day (column) contains the temperatures 10, 11 and 12. The lowest temperature is 10. Then I check the highest forecast temperature. The forecast temperatures for this day are ALL the temperatures after this day. Based on this the highest forecast temperature on day 1 is 20. Now I check if 10 and 20 are in the same row (village). They are obviously not. Then I check again from day 2 and so on. The first number of the output is the total number of days when this happens, and the other numbers are these days' numbers (the columns they are in).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But shouldn't the second input then yield `3 1 2 3` because both the maximum forecast temperature and the minimum temperature of the day are always reached in all 3 villages, and thus the condition is fulfilled on all three days?

Comment: That's entirely possible, sorry about that. I also have that longer input I mentioned, maybe you could also take a quick look at that? https://www33.zippyshare.com/v/avNI69V4/file.html This is a sample input which was not thought out and written by me. How is the last day a valid output here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting `6 1 1 1 2 2 2` for the second example is that you're not stopping to check whether a particular day fulfils the condition once you have found that it does. Thus you find that on day 1 the condition is fulfilled for  village 1, village 2 and village 3 (the first three 1s in the result), and then the same happens for day 2.

From the comment

> tried an i++ here, didn't work as intended

I guess you already identified that problem and the `i++` was intended to prevent rechecking the same day again. However, as you noticed, that alone doesn't work - the reason here is that when skipping ahead to the next day you need to ensure that for that day checking the condition again starts with village 1 and the search for the highest temperature needs to begin from the start as well.

To do so, just add

```
++i;   // carry on with the next day
j = 0; // start with the first village in the next iteration
k = i; // search for the highest temperature beginning from day i + 1
       // note that at the end of the loop body `k` will be incremented
       // so we need to use `k = i` instead of `k = i + 1` as in the loop-initializer here.
```

after `cnt++` in place of the comment I quoted above.

With this change one gets the output you described in the question for both cases, as you can see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e7hSqRmFwyQCDjtv).

Given the input you uploaded to zippyshare I believe that the output for the second example should indeed be `3 1 2 3` instead of `2 1 2`. Luckily the code is easy to change to accomodate that: Just replace all `k = i + 1`s by `k = i` and change the newly added `k = i` to `k = i - 1` so that searching for the highest forecasts includes the present day.